# html link hover not working after link visited?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

in css I define the behavior of the text links like this:

```
a:link {
    color: gray;
}

a:active {
    color: #9999ff;
}

a:hover {
    color: #9999ff;
}

a:visited {
    color: gray;
}
```

Works fine. After I visited a link it should/ and does still have the same color. BUT, and that's what I don't get... after I visited a link it does not hover anymore. How can I make the text link behave the same way always: e.g. link:gray hover:blue???

Thx

Comment: This is just a guess, but what if you put the hover rule _after_ the visited rule. CSS is, to an extent, order specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Frits van Campen is correct, the visited pseudo-class selector is overriding the hover selector, [this fiddle has it fixed.](http://jsfiddle.net/V96r4/)

```
a:link {
    color: gray;
}
a:active {
    color: #9999ff;
}
a:visited {
    color: gray;
}
a:hover {
    color: #9999ff;
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to specify visited if you aren't using it. And you can simplify this code: `a {color: gray;} a:active, a:hover {color: #99f;}`

Comment: @aaronburrows obviously its the same color, but maybe OP wanted to use different colors, but didn't bother including that detail in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue.

Rules of the same specificity will apply according to the order they were defined.

You should move the more important rules to the bottom of the list, so they take precedence.

Comment: Did not know that. Thanks a lot to you too! :-)

Comment: For more information on CSS specificity, check out [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) for an excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Any pseudo-class you don't need, simply do not define it

NB: 1. follow this ordering of a to ensure styling apply to  links
2. It's not necessary to specify {visited, focus, active} if you aren't using it.

```
a,
a:link {
  color: fontColor(color2);
  text-decoration-color: fontColor(color4) !important;
  text-underline-position: under; // to increase the gap between text and underlining in CSS
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration-color: fontColor(color2) !important;
}
```

// mind you am using SCSS (fontColor(color2))

Answer (score 0):

###Try this I think it will work###
**hover** MUST come after **link** and  **visited** in the CSS definition in order to be effective **active** MUST come after **hover** in the CSS definition in order to be effective.
Copied from w3school

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31852570)